# I am trying to send data from one page to another in nextjs but failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Its giving this error "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." Please help.

```
export default function PostScreen() {
      const data = 'Hello';
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <span>Create Post</span>
    
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: '/details',
                query: data, 
              }}
            >
              <a>Click me</a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    // Another page
    function Details(){
      const router = useRouter();
      const data = router.query;
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <strong>Username:</strong> {data}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`query` in `href` accepts an object with key value pairs. If you pass `string`, it will convert the variable's value of the string to `key` and its value will be empty;

If you do a `console.log(data)` on the `/details` page, you get the following:

```js
{ Hello: '' }
```

`React` doesn't support rendering JS objects in the JSX. Hence, you see that error.

So, to solve your problem, you can give some key to the data and use that key in `/details` page to get your data.

For example:

```
export default function PostScreen() {
  const data = 'Hello';
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Create Post</span>
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: '/details',
          query: { message: data }, 
        }}
      >
        <a>Click me</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
    
// "/details" page
function Details(){
  const router = useRouter();
  const data = (router.query ?? {}).message;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <strong>Username:</strong> {data}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this just solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Route.query is a object. you should unpack it first, like:

```
const {id} = data
```

Then pass id to the HTML